# What are my options for plugging holes in soffit for security cameras?

Tags: wiring, security, soffit

I've recently installed some security cameras, but due to attic access through the soffit, I ended out having to drill some holes away from where the cameras were actually mounted. What are my options for plugging these holes?

[image: view of soffit, with two holes in wood approx 3/4" in diameter, with wires coming from one hole leading to two security cameras]

One YouTube video I watched, the guy used some low-profile junction box, but I can't seem to find anything of similar size, for under like $10/each.

Can I just cut a piece of wood, route a channel for the cable, and then screw that to my (wooden) soffit? A 4"x4" piece of wood would be plenty large enough to cover the hole and have room for screws left over. Or is there something besides "junction box" that I should be searching for?

Comment: Including some pictures would be very helpful to getting good answers. Use the "edit" button below your question's text, select the "moon and mountains" icon, and you can upload photos to be included in your question.

Comment: Is your issue plugging extra holes from pulling the wire or covering the wire from where it exits the hole and goes to the camera?

Comment: vinyl plank samples are that size, and tough.

Comment: Without a photo we really can’t help the distance away from the hole would be a guess the size of the hole you drilled would be a guess and the type of soffit you actually have would be a guess. VTC

Comment: Added a photo, FWIW

Comment: You ask about plugging holes, but you also ask about channels for wires. What are your goals? Why didn't you drill new holes so the cables were properly concealed?

Comment: I'm not worried about concealing the wires - I asked about channels because pinching wires between two pieces of wood is a great way to destroy wires. The camera mounts are designed to either be mounted directly over a hole, or as these two are. The aesthetics are the bottom of my list. Safety is my #1 concern - right now insects and elements can get inside these holes. Insects and other pests, mainly, are the concern. The physics of the house/soffit space prevents drilling holes that completely conceals the wires.

Comment: Exterior silicone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plug the hole with exterior silicone caulking. It comes in squeeze tubes or caulking gun tubes. That's probably all you need.

For a more aesthetic finish, and a hard cover to prevent stubborn rodents to bite through (though unlikely needed), you can apply a an exterior cable cover. This is best done in one step, with the caulking still fresh and uncured.

[image]